# How to create a turn-based tactics game in Android? (andengine, unity3d, cocos2d..)

Tags: android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, andengine, game-engine

I would like to know how you could make a game of this genre on Android.
You need to create a map, objects (sprites) and sequences of animations with sprites.

It is impossible to create a game based on XML elements as imageview etc. .. What tool, library, framework recommended for this? If possible free, (not unity3d), cocos2d, andengine, opengl..?

What's the best game-engine?

[image]

Comment: OpenGL would be overkill for your project. Unity3D is sort of free now (for the most part, see their new licensing), but may still be overkill. Cocos2D is not made for this type of game. AndEngine should be your best bet in this case (I suppose Unity3D could do it too). There are other game engines on Android, but I don't know them very well.

Comment: By the way, it should be possible to create a game based on imageviews (and/or using the Canvas). Difficult may be, but not impossible.

Comment: @ephramd - this site is for programming related questions. You question is a bit too open-ended for what goes on here. (see the FAQ). But you can find a lot of what you seek as well as a bunch of fellow game devs on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. Some tips to get you started: You can use andengine, yes. It is free, yes. And you'll want to read up on using TMX tile maps. Good luck with your game.

Answer (score 4):

Google "Tiled Map Editor"

http://www.mapeditor.org/

This will solve a lot of problems related to level building and reduce the need of xmls in a lot of places,

You can use it with many game engines, including AndEngine.